# Creating Toolbox objects (e.g. Labels etc.) in code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, object, toolbox

I'm new at using Microsoft Visual Studio, but I have some knowledge about C++ language. I'd like to create object can be found in Toolbox, such as Labels, Button, etc., but without putting them onto the window by hand.

How can I do it?

Comment: They cannot be created in C++, a language called C++/CLI needs to be used.  Get yourself a book about Winforms programming to get ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects/Controls like labels and buttons are simply a special type of window, with associated window class and window procedure. As such, you call [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and supply for the second parameter, lpClassName, the class name of object/control you want to create (eg. for a label use the class name `STATIC`).

Check out the [following tutorial](http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/windows/windows_tutorial_3.shtm) for a complete example, using the BUTTON class

To create a button:

```
HWND hWndButton=CreateWindowEx(NULL, 
    "BUTTON",
    "OK",
    WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
    50,
    220,
    100,
    24,
    hWnd,
    (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    NULL);`
```